# If an electron turns into a black hole, does it retain its charge?

Tags: black-holes, electrons, charge, quantum-gravity, theory-of-everything

If an electron becomes a black hole, does it retain its charge? Or does it lose it? What if a proton becomes a black hole?

Comment: Charge is one of the properties a black hole can have, yes. So if a proton fell into one, the black hole would gain +1e of charge. However, it's a little unclear what you mean about an electron or a proton becoming a black hole.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it would have to get rid of its charge and much of its angular momentum.

In the black hole electron reference in Wikipedia, by Alfred Centuari, explains why it's not likely that an electron could be a black hole (BH). Essentially, for its small mass, if it keeps the charge and rotation it becomes a Kerr Newman BH. But unfortunately it would be super-extremal, meaning it would not have a horizon. It'd be a naked singularity, or it would have shed most of its charge (and they don't come in continuous units) and angular momentum (also not continuous).

Whatever it would then be, it won't be a BH.

We'd have to have a quantum gravity theory to account for what it may be. Only with that could we possibly account for a naked singularity. But then we'd also need to incorporate quantum electrodynamics, because of the charge. So, we're stretto far from thinking it could be a BH. All those arguments above point to no.

Comment: I get that a blackhole can't be formed with the little amount of mass an electron as for its charge. But I feel we can straightaway discard any possibility of an electron becoming something as an electron is simply an electron with no "structure". So, I don't think there is any possibility of contracting it or increasing its mass so as to make it a blackhole. That is to say any elementary particle with mass, charge, and angular momenta appropriate for a sub-extremal BH would also not make a BH out of itself. Am I missing something?

Comment: It does not seem that elementary particles are black holes. They are other things, like stringy things or something else. That does not eliminate the possibility of having microscopic or small black holes

Answer (score 1):

From the *Minimum mass of a black hole* section of the Wikipedia article [Micro black hole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micro_black_hole#Minimum_mass_of_a_black_hole)

> In principle, a black hole can have any mass equal to or above the
>   Planck mass (about 22 micrograms).

The mass of an electron is about $9.11 \times 10^{-22}$ micrograms which is *much* less than the minimum black hole mass given above.

However, there are electrically charged black hole solutions such as the [Reissner–Nordström metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reissner%E2%80%93Nordstr%C3%B6m_metric).

Lastly, there's the Wikipedia article [Black hole electron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole_electron) which looks at the speculative idea that the electron itself is some type of black hole.